# Facebook Login PHP (not getting email)

Tags: php, facebook, email, facebook-php-sdk

I have been read lot of topics about this, my email is set on primary but I can't retrieve it with Facebook login SDK, I'm using scope as well but still no email.

I just don't know where I should make changes right now lines that includes email scope.

```
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
  // graph api request for user data
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me?scope=email' );
  $response = $request->execute();
  // get response
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

  var_dump($graphObject);
        $fbid = $graphObject->getProperty('id');              // To Get Facebook ID
        $fbfullname = $graphObject->getProperty('name'); // To Get Facebook full name
        $femail = $graphObject->getProperty('email');    // To Get Facebook email ID
    /* ---- Session Variables -----*/
        $_SESSION['FBID'] = $fbid;           
        $_SESSION['FULLNAME'] = $fbfullname;
        $_SESSION['EMAIL'] =  $femail;
    /* ---- header location after session ----*/
  header("Location: /ico/");
} else {
  $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'email'));
 header("Location: ".$loginUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Scope is for login, you need to use the fields parameter:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me?fields=name,email');
```

Comment: But it is for login, like user logins and server side dose not receive email from facebook, just tested with your line, still same

Comment: you misunderstood. the scope parameter is used for login only. if you want to request data from the graph api later, you have to use the fields parameter. your code was definitely wrong. if you still do not get the email, make sure you get asked for the email permission in the login dialog. also, make sure the email is approved and the user actually logs in with the email.

Comment: no i still have same problem... just dont get why i dont receive email in app settings everything is ok email is requested..

Comment: try the api call in the api explorer, after selecting your app in the upper right corner. debug the access token in the token debugger. do some digging.

Answer (score 0):

Some possible reasons:

1. No Email address on account
2. No confirmed email address on account
3. No verified email address on account
4. User entered a security checkpoint which required them to reconfirm their email address and they have not yet done so
5. Users's email address is unreachable
6. If the user denies a permission, FB will not ask for the same permission again. For that you have to follow the `re-request` method.
7. In certain cases I have also observed that if the user has logged in using their phone number, FB doesn't return their email. However, I am not entirely sure about this scenario. There may be other factors affecting it.